# What are cuda resources and cuda devices?

Tags: parallel-processing, graphics, cuda, gpu

I read the cuda api documentation but could not understand what the two mean. I want to know what CUdevice and cuResource. I have a rough understanding that CUdevice refers to one GPU device but still have no idea what cuGraphicsResource means.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a rough understanding that CUdevice refers to one GPU device

Correct. A `CUdevice` is the CUDA [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html) method to refer to a device, for those API calls that need it such as [`cuCtxCreate()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g65dc0012348bc84810e2103a40d8e2cf).  For that API call, it indicates which device is the intended target.

> what cuGraphicsResource means

This handle is used in [CUDA/Graphics interop](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__GRAPHICS.html#group__CUDA__GRAPHICS).  It is one of the elements used to exchange data between the GPU operating as a graphics processor (e.g. OpenGL), and the GPU acting as a compute device (e.g. CUDA).

A graphics resource refers to a graphics entity, typically including such things as textures, Frame Buffer Objects, Pixel Buffer Objects, and Vertex Buffer Objects.  Each one of those graphics entities can have data associated with it, and the `cuGraphicsResource` is a named handle (in the driver API) to use to refer to that data or a container ("resource") that includes that data.